# ApplePay using stripe-react-native show Payment Not Completed while return payment method result

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble integrating ApplePay using stripe-react-native lib to my app. I followed the guide in stripe doc and manage to open the payment sheet. But when proceed to payment the UI loading for a bit then show 'Payment Not Completed!' then close the sheet. However the payment function still return the success result (payment method info).
[Fail payment on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bIjV.jpg)

My implementation code:

App.js

```
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StripeProvider     publishableKey="pk_test_51L6AWmGROtrteUVR8vR4WLpcNT1KFiHJjWYjGYiYB0Fwh0HdRDkbj9fy4Hlp88z1S76TufwTL755QUnWswWUUhOT00UijEYwS3"
        merchantIdentifier="merchant.com.adamo.dropr"
      >
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <StackNavigation />
          <FlashMessage position="top" floating={true} hideStatusBar={false} />
          <GlobalUI ref={GlobalService.globalUIRef} />
        </PersistGate>
      </StripeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
```

open payment sheet file:

```
const pay = async () => {
    // ...
    const { paymentMethod, error } = await presentApplePay({
      cartItems: [
        {
          label: "Example item name",
          amount: "100.00",
          isPending: false,
          paymentType: "Immediate",
        },
      ],
      country: "GB",
      currency: "GBP",
      shippingMethods: [
        {
          amount: "20.00",
          identifier: "DPS",
          label: "Courier",
          detail: "Delivery",
          isPending: true,
        },
      ],
      requiredShippingAddressFields: ["emailAddress", "phoneNumber"],
      requiredBillingContactFields: ["phoneNumber", "name"],
    });
    console.log(paymentMethod);

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("success");
    }
    // ...
  };

{isApplePaySupported && (
              <ApplePayButton
                onPress={pay}
                type="plain"
                buttonStyle="black"
                borderRadius={8}
                style={{
                  marginTop: Spacing.height5,
                  width: Spacing.width157,
                  height: Spacing.height52,
                }}
              />
            )}
```

And I already had the apple pay certificate added to the Stripe dashboard.
[Stripe dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhsOY.png)

Please tell me if I missing something in the configuration or did something wrong with the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two parts in the Apple Pay flow.

The first part is to call `presentApplePay()` to present the Apple PaymentSheet to your customer, so that they can choose the payment method for this payment. You've implemented the first part correctly.

The second part is to call `confirmApplePayPayment()` to submit the payment to Stripe, and this is missing in your flow. You should first send a request to your backend to create a PaymentIntent, and pass the PaymentIntent's `client_secret` back to your iOS app, so that you can call `confirmApplePayPayment()` with the returned `client_secret`.

You can refer to this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=react-native#handle-payment) and learn how to submit payment to Stripe. This guide also provides example code that you can directly use in your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never thought that it must complete all logic